# Is the JavaScript Array.length property a function or a simple variable?

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript code. I have initialised an array using the new keyword, and therefore creating a new instance of the array object. I then populate the array by adding elements to it.

However I think I have made a fundamental misunderstanding - it is the next part of the code that has massively confused me, please correct my terminology if it is not clear enough or it is just plain wrong. I have logged     `(beatles.length)`. I am using the length property to find out how many elements are in the array. But why is it that length is a property and not a method?

Is it not the case that length is actually a method that the Array object can invoke that returns a numeric value? If length is not a method then why is it a property (a variable belonging to the array object)? Please explain the distinction here in a succinct way.

```
var beatles = new Array();
beatles[0] = "John";
beatles[1] = "Paul";
beatles[2] = "George";
beatles[3] = "Ringo";

console.log(beatles.length);
```

Comment: It's less memory intensive to have it be an integer property that changes on every array change than calling a method every time. In some JS engines, it may be a getter method.

Comment: Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It **is** a property that gets increased or decreased as you push elements to the array object.

For example my (fake) object:

```
var myArray = function(){
   this.length = 0;

   this.push = function(itm){
       this.length++; 
       // ^ doesn't do anything aside from increase length
   };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Both `String` and `Arrays` are of the type `Objects` and are not basic variable types.

So, the `length` is a member variable of the `Object` generic object and is commonly available to both Array as well as String. In case of String, it returns the string length and in the case of Array, it returns the count, by overriding.

A small example would be:

```
var a = "Hello";
var b = new Array();
b[0] = "Hello";
b[1] = "World";
a.length    // returns 5
b.length    // returns 2
```

Comment: Although both `String` and `Array` have `.length`, it's NOT a member of `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

there is no need for `.length` to be a function, since it doesn't need to be recalculated every time, but rather it's increased or decreased as needed as you push elements onto your `[]` object.

while functions *can be* idempotent, properties are **always** idempotent, which makes `.length` a better fit as well.

functions generally change state (like `.push`), or return different values based on the arguments they receive (`.slice`, `.splice`).

on a different note:

the preferred way to initialize arrays is `var a = [];`, and to add elements you should use `a.push(element);`

Comment: Is the **idempotent** statement still true for the new ES5/6 standard? Will there be provisions to prevent mutations in get-implementation? That would be a bit strange.

Answer (score 2):

`length` is a **pseudo-property**, there is something going on under-the-hood to make it work like it does.

`length` behaves like a getter and a setter in one (like a function). You access it like a property, but you can't delete it like a property: `delete beatles.length` (will fail).

If you add elements to the Array the `length` property will change accordingly.

If you *set* the length property, the Array will change - `beatles.length = 0;` will clear the Array.

Right now there is no way to make similar functionality yourself (short of using explicit get/setter). Some of this will become available in the new ES5 (or 6?) standard. Like the ability to make immutable properties. That *magic* of indexed assignments will be specific to Arrays though, that's a language feature.

As for *why* the language designer made it property instead of a function .. well, perhaps performance, perhaps similarity to other languages (most notably Java of course).

Source:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/set

Answer (score 2):

The `Array.length` property is actually an encapsulation of two (hidden) methods, `get()` and a `set()` , also referred to as accessors.

JavaScript internally calls `get()` when you use the property in an expression, e.g.:

```
var n = fields.length;
```

Conversely, it calls `set()` when used in an assignment, e.g.:

```
fields.length = 1;
```

Doing so also updates the array items to satisfy the following condition.

> The value of the `length` property is always one higher than the biggest item index (or zero if there are none);

This is an important detail, because in certain cases it will not strictly be the same as the number of (non-null) items in the array.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `length` is a property which is always kept valid by the javascript engine itself.

Answer (score 1):

**It's a property, but it's unlike any other property in the whole language**.

Arrays aren't *quite* the same kind of object that you're familiar with (though they do come quite close). The spec defines a special type of object, called an *Array exotic object*, just to keep the `length` property working quite the way it should, and all Arrays are actually this kind of exotic object, rather than standard objects. There are a few other kinds of exotic objects, too, but the one for Arrays is what concerns us here.

The basics of the `length` property seem simple enough: it's the number of elements in the Array. But **keeping this up-to-date requires a considerable amount of behind-the-scenes magic. Even getters and setters can't completely handle it.**

The reason comes from the actual definition of the Array `length` property: if you look at the property names of an object, it might be possible to express some of them as numbers, and if this is possible, then one of the numbers must be larger than all of the others. Array exotic objects always have a property called `length`, and that property's value must always be larger than the largest such number for its object. **If other properties change, then the Array's `length` might have to change too, depending on the name of the other property. So it has to monitor all property changes, to make sure that it updates when it's supposed to**.

**Currently, there's no way to do that in JavaScript**. You can have functions monitor changes to a *specific* property, by using setters, but you can't have a general function to monitor *all* property changes on an object. **ECMAScript 6 looks like it will have a way to do this**, via Proxy objects, but there aren't any browsers that support it completely just yet.

Comment: Well, you *could* do a getter for the `.length` and every time it is accessed search the whole array index space for the highest one :-)

Comment: @Bergi: That's true. I guess you could do that. It wouldn't scale very well to large Arrays, though.

Comment: @Bergi Is there a way to reconfigure an array's length property to have a getter? I believe it's not configurable.

Comment: @Redu Yes, native arrays have a non-configurable `length`