# In Node, is Buffer.length a static property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, v8

When we use `Buffer.length`, is this a static property? Or does it have to do work to calculate its length?

Comment: I believe it's implemented in a similar way to Array.length. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14464624/8943850) answer explained it pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a property. It doesn't do any calculations.